# Python itertools combinations length

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

Would appreciate any input about this practice problem:

Given a string of length `n` and an integer `k`, print all possible combinations of length `k` (Print nCk) under the constraint that `1` <= `k` <= `n`. You can assume no repeating characters

Examples:

> abc, 2 --> ab, bc, ca
>
> abc, 1 --> a, b, c
>
> abc, 3 --> abc

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools

def func(data, r):
    return ["".join(x) for x in itertools.combinations(data, r)]
```

Comment: Some explanation would help.

Comment: Thanks Rain.  I understand your answer, works great.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer Rain, works great.

Answer:

```
import itertools

def func(data, r):
    return ["".join(x) for x in itertools.combinations(data, r)]

print(func('abc', 2))
print(func('abc', 1))
print(func('abc', 3))
```

Output:

```
['ab', 'ac', 'bc']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['abc']
```

Notes:

**itertools.combinations(iterable, r)**

*Return r length subsequences of elements from the input iterable.*

Combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input iterable is sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted order